# My iMessages are still merging even though we have separate Apple IDs

Tags: icloud, messages

My phones messages are still syncing with my iPad's even though both devices have separate IDs. The only device I'm signed in on is my phone, yet everything is still synced? I was wondering how to unsync both devices completely?

Answer (score 1):

Changing Apple ID won't remove previous messages received, only future messages. In the Messages app, you will have to manually delete each conversation to remove the message history.